# SQL insert data into table has foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Background: SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2008 R2

```
DataTable: ProductID(PK, bigint), ProductNameID(FK, int), Price(Decimal)

ProductNameTable: ProductNameID(PK, int), ProductName(varchar)
```

So I need to insert data like "123.4, AAA" (Price, ProductName) into DataTable but with ProductNameID is a FK,

How can I do that???? Bec ProductNameID is auto-increment

This is the code I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DataInsertSP        
@Price DECIMAL(8, 2),    @ProductName VARCHAR(20)       
AS
BEGIN     

DECLARE @NewProductNameID INT    

INSERT INTO ProductNameTable(ProductName)    
VALUES (@ProductName)    

SELECT @NewProductNameID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()    

INSERT INTO DataTable(ProductNameID, Price)    
VALUES (@NewProductNameID, @Price);
END;

EXECUTE DataInsertSP 
@Price = 12.25        ,   @ProductName = 'Argo'
```

Please give me some advice, Thanks so much

Comment: what is wrong with the existing code looks fine to me, Except that you need to `@NewProductNameID` to be `BIGINT`.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Any reason you have two different tables? Since both price and name are dependent upon the productID, you'd want a single table for all this data in order to be in normal form.

Comment: In retail businesses it is a very common practice to have multiple prices for one product (time-to-time, Area-to-Area), therefore having a separate table for product prices does make a lot of sense.

Comment: That's true, good point, but in this case you wouldn't need ProductNameID stored along with the price.

Comment: Hmm, I did thought of that should I put everything in one table?? but then I read lots of DB design warning never put everything in one table, but reality is my DB is really a simple one, but everyday will have 5000+ data insert, should I put them all in one table or separate?? What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Thing I can think of is what if the Product name already exists? for this you can write this procedure a bit differently by adding a little check. Something like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DataInsertSP        
   @Price       DECIMAL(8, 2),    
   @ProductName VARCHAR(20)       
AS
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON;   

  DECLARE @NewProductNameID BIGINT;    

SELECT @NewProductNameID = ProductID
FROM ProductNameTable
WHERE ProductName =  @ProductName

IF (@NewProductNameID IS NULL)
 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO ProductNameTable(ProductName)    
     VALUES (@ProductName)    
     SELECT @NewProductNameID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
 END

 INSERT INTO DataTable(ProductNameID, Price)    
 VALUES (@NewProductNameID, @Price);

END;
```

Comment: Hi, @M.Ali so one more question, Should I put some Stats column in DataTable? eg. MeanOfPrice, SumOfPrice??? The content of these column is done before write into Database

Comment: There should be no Stats table. Create views to pull this information at run time.

Comment: appreciated your advice, but I also design a web app GridView to pull all these data, there will have 5000+ new data insert everyday, if 100000+ data selected by user, will it be too slow if I pull stats data at run time?

Comment: In this case I would suggest look into indexed views.